BIRT database connection details from file
I want to specify a database connection details from an external connection profile file.
config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<DataTools.ServerProfiles version="1.0">
    <profile autoconnect="No" desc="" id="d04355a1-7c01-11ef-878c-9abc7ec407b6" name="claim2me_db_profile" providerID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc">
        <baseproperties>
            <property name="odaUser" value="user"/>
            <property name="metadataBidiFormatStr" value="ILYNN"/>
            <property name="odaDriverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="odaJndiName" value=""/>
            <property name="odaPassword" value="pass"/>
            <property name="disabledMetadataBidiFormatStr" value=""/>
            <property name="contentBidiFormatStr" value="ILYNN"/>
            <property name="odaURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-postgres-database"/>
            <property name="disabledContentBidiFormatStr" value=""/>
        </baseproperties>
    </profile>
</DataTools.ServerProfiles>

After creating the file and having the data source pointing at it the BIRT report designer keeps saving these lines in the report file. How can i stop it from saving these lines?
report.rptdesign
    <property name="odaDriverClass">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="odaURL">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-postgres-database</property>
    <property name="odaUser">use</property>

Couldn't find other way to have the connection details in a separate files. The internet only gives incomplete answers.

I'm afraid you can't.
The only solution is to delete those lines manually before deploying the file or saving it in a Git Repository.
Of course, be sure to test if the report works without those lines.
